# Automatically populate SQL column based on foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Table 1:

```
parent_id string_id
5001      a
8759      b
3957      c
```

string_id is the primary key for Table 1.
parent_id has an UNIQUE constraint on it.

Table 2:

```
child_id parent_id string_id
1        5001      a
2        8759      b
3        3957      c
```

child_id is the primary key for Table 2.
string_id is the foreign key to Table 1.

When I populate new row into Table 2, I do **NOT** want to insert the parent_id in my query by **joining/merging** Table 1.

```
INSERT INTO table_2 (string_id)
VALUES ('a'),
       ('b'),
       ('c')
```

Could anyone give me suggestion whether SQL can populate the parent_id automatically by using built in relationship (e.g. constraint, foreign keys, cascade)? If join is the only way, could you also let me know so that I can stop investigating?

Basically, I want to know what is the most elegant way of solving this problem. I could use join with INSERT, but I think that is an ugly query for such a simple functionality.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of storing tables with foreign key constraints is so that the data does not need to be duplicated. SQL then offers the `JOIN` for looking up values.

I would strongly encourage you to use `JOIN` to look up the `parent_id` when you need it. If you like, you can write the query once and use a `JOIN` -- and then anyone using the view would have the `parent_id`.